# VueJS Laravel - Uploading image using Axios post error: 'The given data was invalid'

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

For school I'm making a blog with some people and now I want to upload an image to the blog post. But then this uploading the post the error:

> {message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {image: ["The image field is required."]}}
>   errors: {image: ["The image field is required."]}
>   message: "The given data was invalid."

I have searched on the internet and looked at other conversations, but I can't find my solution.
Here are my codes:

This is the form in a VueJS component:

```
<form method="post" action="./api/post" @submit.prevent="createPost()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Titel van de post</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Titel van de post" name="title" v-model="title">
    <p>Beschrijving bij de post</p>
    <textarea placeholder="Beschrijving bij de post" name="description" v-model="description"/>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" ref="image" v-on:change="(e) => {this.onChangeFileUpload(e)}"/>
    <div class="uploadtimer">
        <p>Selecteer een tijd wanneer de post moet worden getoond. (Niet verplicht)</p>
        <datetime format="YYYY-MM-DD H:i" v-model="uploadTime"></datetime>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="input-submit">
</form>
```

The script in the component:

```
<script>
import datetime from 'vuejs-datetimepicker';

export default {
    components: { datetime },
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            uploadTime: '',
            image: '',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onChangeFileUpload(e) {
            this.image = e.target.files[0];
        },
        createPost() {
            let data = new FormData;
            data.append('image', this.image);

            axios.post('./api/post', {
                title: this.title,
                description: this.description,
                data,
                uploadTime: this.uploadTime,

            }).then(response => {

            }).catch(response => {
                document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.display = 'flex';
                document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = '<span>!</span><p>Er is iets mis gegaan met het plaatsen van de post.</p>';
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.display = 'none';
                }, 5000);
            });


        }
    },
}
```

And the Controller function I'm using:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::check()) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);

        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->description = $request->input('description');

        $image = $request->file('image');

        $imageExtension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $imageName = time() . '_' . $imageExtension;

        $image->move(public_path('/imgs/users-avatars/'), $imageName);

        $post->image = '/imgs/posts-images/' . $imageName;

        $post->uploadTime = $request->input('uploadTime');
        $post->user_id = Auth::User()->id;

        $post->save();

        return (['message' => 'succes']);
    } else {
        return (['message' => 'error', 'handler' => 'Authenticated user is required!']);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either `image` rule (that validates a file to be jpeg, png, bmp, gif, svg, or webp) or use `mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg`:

So your validation would be either:

```php
'image' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
```

Or:

```php
'image' => 'required|file|image|max:2048',
```

Additionally, the `file` rule checks if the field is a successfully uploaded file and `max:2048` rule checks if the file size is less than or equal to 2048 kilobytes (2MB). See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation) for more info.

On VueJs, you have to append all your inputs to a `FormData`:

```js
let data = new FormData;
data.append('image', this.image);
data.append('title', this.title);
data.append('description', this.description);
data.append('uploadTime', this.uploadTime);

axios.post('./api/post', data)
    .then(
    //...
```

Comment: {message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: {image: ["The image must be a file.", "The image must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg."]}
message: "The given data was invalid."

Comment: @JensBouma have you changed your js as above? your file may be corrupted, try with another one.

Comment: Yes I've changed it. When I'm uploading a file with .png extension it still gives the error 'The image must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg'

Comment: Nvm I used on one place imge instead of image

Comment: @HafezDivandari this worked for me. At first I was trying to pass my data as an object within the axios.post call but it didn't work. Why does setting the data as a ```new FormData``` object work in Vue.js? Can you link the docs on this? Great answer, thanks!