# Laravel Image Validation

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file, validation, axios

I am writing a vue component where users can upload a profile picture that I want to validate on the backend using Laravel's built-in [image validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-image). I use an axios post call with a JSON object that has the following key value pair.

[image: JSON for File]

When I go the backend I send it through a custom Laravel request and put the following validation rule on it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Department;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ChangePersonalInfo extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        if(auth()->user()) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    /**
     * Convert certain request parameters before validation
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
      $this->merge([
        'assigned_states' => explode(',', $this->assigned_states),
        'customer_price_level' => json_encode($this->customer_price_level),
        'customer_price_list' => json_encode($this->customer_price_list),
        'customer_type' => json_encode($this->customer_type),
        'email_notifications' => filter_var($this->email_notifications, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'employee' => filter_var($this->employee, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'read_notification_terms' => filter_var($this->read_notification_terms, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'reviewed' => filter_var($this->reviewed, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'text_notifications' => filter_var($this->text_notifications, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'verified' => filter_var($this->verified, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'termsCode' => json_encode($this->termsCode)
      ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
      $departments = Department::select(['department_name'])->pluck('department_name')->toArray();

      return [
          'api_token' => 'string|alpha_num',
          'assigned_states' => 'array|nullable',
          'assigned_states_description' => 'string|nullable',
          'avatar_file' => 'string|nullable',
          'bc_details' => 'string|json|nullable',
          'bc_guid' => 'string|nullable',
          'company_address_id' => 'numeric|integer|nullable',
          'company_name' => 'string|nullable',
          'company_website' => 'string|nullable',
          'created_at' => 'string|nullable',
          'customer_price_level' => 'json',
          'customer_price_list' => 'json',
          'customer_type' => 'json',
          'customer_price_level.id' => 'numeric|integer',
          'customer_price_list.id' => 'numeric|integer',
          'customer_type.id' => 'numeric|integer',
          'department' => ['string', 'nullable', Rule::in($departments)],
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'email_notifications' => 'boolean',
          'employee' => 'boolean',
          'first_name' => 'string|nullable|max:30',
          'id' => 'string|integer|alpha_num',
          'imageExtension' => 'string|nullable',
          'imageFile' => 'sometimes|nullable|image|max:2048',
          'last_name' => 'string|nullable|max:30',
          'marketing_preferences' => 'string|nullable',
          'notes' => 'string|nullable',
          'price_level_id' => 'required|numeric|integer',
          'price_list_id' => 'numeric|integer|nullable',
          'primary_address_id' => 'numeric|integer|nullable',
          'pimary_billing_address' => 'numeric|integer|nullable',
          'primary_phone_number_id' => 'numeric|integer|nullable',
          'read_notification_terms' => 'boolean',
          'reviewed' => 'boolean',
          'statusName' => 'string',
          'status_id' => 'numeric|integer|nullable',
          'termsCode' => 'json',
          'termsCode.id' => 'numeric|integer',
          'terms_code_id' => 'numeric|integer|required',
          'text_notifications' => 'boolean',
          'timezone' => 'timezone',
          'title' => 'string|nullable',
          'type_id' => 'required|numeric|integer',
          'updated_at' => 'string|nullable',
          'username' => 'string|nullable',
          'verificationStatus' => 'string',
          'verification_token' => 'string|nullable',
          'verified' => 'boolean'
      ];
  }
}
```

I'm getting a 500 error back with this message.

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"imageFile":["The image file must be an image."]}}
```

Could anyone help me know why it appears to be an image file on the frontend but fails to meet the backend validation?

Comment: Can i see your laravel full code?

Comment: See this question solve your problem or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817409/vuejs-laravel-uploading-image-using-axios-post-error-the-given-data-was-inva

Answer (score -2):

check this format

```php
  'imageFile' => 'required|file|max:512|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can Try This

```
'image' => 'required|file|image|max:2048'
```

Answer (score -2):

I used the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) in order to get this work. It was fairly simple after that with a basic axios post request. I will add the finalized code I used. This JavaScript code was able to send an image properly to the backend which was validated in Laravel as an image.

```
let formData = new FormData();
Object.keys(this.form).forEach(key => {
 formData.append(key, this.form[key]);
});
formData.append('imageFile', this.imageFile);

axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: this.routes.save,
  data: formData
})
```